# Как нарисовать график синуса, по входным параметрам?

Tags: c#, winforms, графика

1. Входные параметры: период и амплитуда
2. График рисуется на форме до отметки 2 ПИ

Благодарю за внимание

Comment: с чем именно проблемы?

Comment: Первый раз работаю с такими объектами, поэтому не могу реализовать в виде кода

Comment: что конкретно не можешь реализовать? ГРафик нарисовать? Можешь взять готовый компонент по отрисовке графиков

Comment: функцию которая его рисует

Comment: Спасибо, теперь знаю что мне нужно найти